# Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock:

Tags: docker, jenkins, docker-compose, docker-machine

Use Case:

Base Instance has a Ubuntus 16.04 
Installed Docker and it works find and I'm able to checkout docker images.

Deployed an Instance of Jenkins Docker container.

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 \
  -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
  --name jenkins \
  jenkins/jenkins:lts
```

This Jenkins Instance will mount the host machine's Docker socket in the container. As Mentioned in the Article.

```
https://getintodevops.com/blog/the-simple-way-to-run-docker-in-docker-for-ci
```

Now installed he docker binaries on the Jenkins container.

```
apt-get update && \
apt-get -y install apt-transport-https \
 ca-certificates \
 curl \
 gnupg2 \
 software-properties-common && \
curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/$(. /etc/os-release; echo "$ID")/gpg > /tmp/dkey; apt-key add /tmp/dkey && \
add-apt-repository \ "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/$(. /etc/os-release; echo "$ID") \
   $(lsb_release -cs) \
   stable" && \
apt-get update && \
apt-get -y install docker-c
```

Ran the Docker ps from the Jenkins conatiner and listed the available Containers.

But when triggering a job from Jenkins it fails withe the below error
+ docker run hello-world
docker: Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Post http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.39/containers/create: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied.

I tried solution provided to add the user to the group but it still fails

https://techoverflow.net/2017/03/01/solving-docker-permission-denied-while-trying-to-connect-to-the-docker-daemon-socket/

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: https://github.com/sudo-bmitch/jenkins-docker

Answer (score -1):

I got this to work.

ADD THE USER TO THE GROUP
STOP AND RESTART THE CONTAINER

Comment: which group? The "docker" group?